# Reposition scroll in Horizontal Listview using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I have created horizontal `ListView` using `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="433px"
    android:layout_height="76px"
    />
```

But the problem is I want to reposition the `scrollBar`, when I try to do that then everything goes wrong. I have tried to add these two lines to RecyclerView:

```
  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
```

If I use those two lines then scrollBar does not go further away from the listview, instead it creates result similar in this image:

[image]

It just shrunks the whole listview's height. Does anyone have other ideas on how to reposition scrollBar or maybe I have messed soething up and I do not understand something?